# How do I properly avoid the usage of a delimiter in a custom string?

Tags: python, security, python-3.5

I am currently working on a Discord Bot that interacts with my gameserver through rcon and came across a problem.

I have two functions. This is for the bot to recognize a command (e.g. '.say Hello World')

````
@bot.command(pass_context=True, aliases=[])
@asyncio.coroutine
def say(context, *, msg):
yield from bot.say("```{0}```".format(rcon.rcon_say(msg)))
````

The second function sends it to my gameserver. In this case 'say Hello World' wich will make the server say 'Hello World' into the chat.

```
def rcon_say(_msg : str):
with RCON(SERVER_ADDRESS, PASSWORD) as rcon:
    return rcon("say {0}".format(_msg))
```

The problem: .say "test; kick user1" will send two commands to the server:

```
 say test
 kick user1
```

so its abusable with any other rcon command. So how to avoid this from beeing abused?

What I did to avoid abusage:

I added following function:

```
def checkMsg(checkThis : str):
if ";" in checkThis:
    raise errors.SemicolonError()
    return
else:
    return checkThis
```

And added

```
 _msg = checkMsg(_msg)
```

So this will remove any semicolons from the users input but I somehow don't feel like it's the right way to do this. Is it still possible to send a semicolon (maybe decoded/ in unicode etc.)

Am I safe or is there a way of abusing it?

Comment: In other words, you need to filter the user input?

Answer (score 0):

you should instead make your delimiter an unprintable character like `'\x00'` ... that would easily solve the issue ...

Comment: Can't change the delimiter because it's set by the game. I'm only coding the bot interacting with that game.